# Getting an issue while integrating google-cloud with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux, google-cloud-platform

I am integrating the google-cloud npm package with my react application and i am using firebase.

Errors i am encountering -

> WARNING in ./~/google-cloud/~/hash-stream-validation/index.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in
>   '/home/linuxbox/React-Workspace/Kaptify/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/hash-stream-validation'
>   @ ./~/google-cloud/~/hash-stream-validation/index.js 5:8-30  @
>   ./~/google-cloud/~/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js  @
>   ./~/google-cloud/~/@google-cloud/storage/src/index.js  @
>   ./~/google-cloud/src/index.js  @ ./src/actions/UserStateStore.js  @
>   ./app.js  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:3000
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./app.js
>
> WARNING in ./~/google-cloud/~/google-auto-auth/index.js 53:13-58
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/google-cloud/~/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js
>   38:14-35 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 19:22-48
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
>   15:20-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: Do you use `google-cloud` in frontend code or backend code? If it's frontend, you probably want to use this library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Answer (score 16):

I see you're using webpack, and I'm assuming you're using the `google-cloud` library in the backend.

Try putting this in your webpack config:

```
config = {
    // ...
    externals: {
        '@google-cloud/storage': 'commonjs @google-cloud/storage'
    },
    // ...
}
```

### Explanation

Modules meant for the backend aren't really made with the intention of them being bundled (see: [Backend Apps with Webpack](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I)). So we use webpack's `externals` config to exclude libraries that don't handle that bundling well. When the app is run, they are just `require()`'ed from the `node_modules` directory as normal.

If you don't want to specify your offending modules one-by-one, try out [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) to automatically exclude all modules.

Comment: How does this solve the issue? When you take the webpacked javascript elsewhere it won't work due to missing modules

Comment: @OdedNiv If you do this for a library you're making, you'll need to have the packages you exclude listed in `dependencies` in `package.json` so anything consuming your library also downloads the necessary modules.

Comment: He says he is integrating google-cloud with his "react application", which is the opposite of a library