# Requiring @google-cloud/language breaks webpack ('Module Not Found')

Tags: webpack, google-cloud-platform, webpack-dev-server, google-cloud-nl

I'm a little baffled at this one, so here goes:

I'm trying to do a React application with a search bar that will call on Google's Natural Language API (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) ,and as part of that I of course installed the '@google-cloud/language' package. However, the moment I try to require it within any of the files (my specific case is `const Language = require('@google-cloud/language');`) and then try to run webpack-dev-server, it it can't find... I think *any* of my modules? It's literally just a giant wall of "Module not found" errors, such as

```
Error in ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in /home/amberb/projects/project-ui/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib

 @ ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js 14:14-32

Error in ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in /home/amberb/projects/project-ui/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib

 @ ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js 17:14-32

Error in ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in /home/amberb/projects/project-ui/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib

 @ ./~/grpc/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js 15:14-32

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
Module parse failed: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
 @ /usr/lib/~/npm/lib/npm.js 453:4-32

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/~/opener/opener.js
Module parse failed: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/opener/opener.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
 @ /usr/lib/~/npm/lib/auth/sso.js 4:13-30

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/~/JSONStream/index.js
Module parse failed: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
 @ /usr/lib/~/npm/lib/search/all-package-metadata.js 12:17-38

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/~/npm-registry-client/lib/initialize.js
Module not found: 'json' in /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib

 @ /usr/lib/~/npm/~/npm-registry-client/lib/initialize.js 5:10-36

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/~/validate-npm-package-name/index.js
Module not found: 'json' in /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/validate-npm-package-name

 @ /usr/lib/~/npm/~/validate-npm-package-name/index.js 4:15-34

Error in /usr/lib/~/npm/~/pacote/lib/util/opt-check.js
Module not found: 'json' in /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/util
```

(this continues for some time)

This does not happen whenever I don't include @google-cloud/language. I can't seem to find any explanation as to what might be doing this. Does anyone know something I could at least try?

Edited to add: After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920761/getting-an-issue-while-integrating-google-cloud-with-webpack?rq=1) came up as a recommended related question, I tried adding

```
externals: {
      '@google-cloud/language': 'commonjs @google-cloud/language'
  }
```

in to my webpack config file, but that only results in my page not loading and giving me `webpack:///external_%22@google-cloud/language%22?:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I'm somewhat new to Webpack still, so I'm positive I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else came here with an issue like this, the problem was ultimately that I was trying to include this package that should not have really been included on the front-end within the front end. We split it off into our back-end API gateway and are calling it from within the front end. As a rule, functionality which makes any API call for which you have to provide authentication and which may incur use costs should be split off into a separate back-end service/function.